# Passing model property to checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

My model

```
public class UserVM
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; } 
    //my windows authentication checkbox property       
    public bool WindowsAuthChk { get; set; }
    //my windows autologin checkbox property  
    public bool AutoLoginChk { get; set; }
}
```

My view(cshtml)

```
@model Models.UserVM
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "signinForm" }))
    {
           <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
            </div>
           <div class="col-sm-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
```

//my checkbox

```
 <div>@Html.CheckBox("checkWindowsAuth",Model.WindowsAuthChk) @Html.Label("Use windows authentication")</div>
```

//which is not working, I want to pass my model property WindowsAuthChk to my checkbox above and get the bool value to controller.....I want to know how to pass bool model property to checkbox in @Html.CheckBox

```
public bool WindowsAuthChk { get; set; }
```

thanks in advance....

Comment: Just tagging it as checkbox might be a bit to general. My guess is you mean C# and MVC?

Comment: can you post the controller code?

Comment: `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => M.WindowsAuthChk)` works fine. If its not, then its because of another issue not related to the code you have shown. And also it should be `@Html.LabelFor(m => M.WindowsAuthChk, "Use windows authentication")` so the label is associated with the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong, you can just use Html.EditorFor(), if the property is a non nullable bool mvc will generate a checkbox for you.

```
@Html.EditorFor(item => item.BoolProp)
```

you could also use the Html.CheckboxFor() methode.

```
@Html.CheckboxFor(item => item.BoolProp)
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/8gyGKN

Comment: There's no item only model, I can pass email and password successfully using m=>m.Email, but I'm not able to use, m=>m.WindowsAuthChk...

Comment: But it should work. Strange. Why would WindowsAuthChk be any different than Email? Put Model.WindowsAuthChk in a {} in your view and set a debug point to make sure the bool is set properly.

Comment: your view code schould be 
<div>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.WindowsAuthChk) @Html.Label("Use windows authentication")</div>

Comment: Cannot convert lambda expression to type Models.UserVM because it is not a delegate type..

Comment: @Geloot :<div>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.WindowsAuthChk)
Same error message:"Cannot convert lambda expression to type Models.UserVM because it is not a delegate type."